# Filter names that weren't found in a SQL select query

Tags: sql, t-sql

To simplify my problem 
I have a list of names:

> ('Jon','Joe','Jane','Dave'..)

and a table filled with the following columns

> Name Age Address

I'm using the following query to select names that exist in the list:

```
SELECT Name,Age,Address from Table1 where Name in ('Jon','Joe','Jane'...)
```

but what I want is to find names in the list that **are not** in the table, how do I do that?

Comment: How is the list of names stored (in another table).   Also, how large is the main table?  There are some string manipulation techniques, but they would not perform very well.   You could also put the names into a temporary table and use NOT in or a LEFT JOIN and Null check

Comment: what version of sql server are you on, 2014, 2016, 2017?

Comment: @Sparky brings up several valid questions.   Basically we need a way of getting the list into a table so you can left join or not in to your main "Table1" and return back out those names in the list not in the table.  So is the list a string you have coming from somewhere and is that the format or are those names maybe stored in another table?

Comment: Just to be clear, if `'Jon'` and `'Jane'` occur in the `Name` column of `Table1`, but `'Joe'` does not you want the result to be `'Joe'`, right? (Not meaning to slight `'Dave'` and the rest of the band.)

Comment: Yes,  @HABO . And i will save the names that weren't found( like 'Joe') in a text file

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `left join` or something similar:

```
select v.name
from (values ('Jon'), ('Joe'), ('Jane'), . . . 
     ) v(name)
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.name = v.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to find the entries that don't have NULL in the name column

```
SELECT Name,Age,Address from Table1 where Name NOT in ('Jon','Joe','Jane'...)
```

This can be used to find the entries where NULL is present in the name column

```
SELECT Name,Age,Address from Table1 where Name NOT in ('Jon','Joe','Jane'...) OR Name IS NULL
```

Comment: While this solution will work, it hard codes the list of names, which I don't think is what is desired.

Comment: These will find the names in the table that are not in the list, but the OP want the names in the _list_ that are not in the _table_.